# No me funciona el comando npm -i -g sass

Tags: npm, sass, console

No puedo descargar sass con este comando:

> npm -i -g sass

No se porque falla.

He intentado

> npm --install -g sass

> npm -i --global sass

> npm --install --global sass

Y sigue sin funcionar Sass

Pueden ayudarme por favor

> Unknown command: "sass"
>
> To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
>
> > npm help

Comment: Por qué dices que falla? Qué error encuentras? Por favor, edita tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quita el guión y vuelve a intentarlo.

Si estás en entornos linux o macOS acuérdate de poner sudo delante del comando.

`sudo npm i -g sass` o bien `npm i -g sass`

### Fallo que debería dar si se usa `-i` en vez de `i`

```
❯ npm -i -g sass
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/marcos/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/marcos/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/marcos/.npm/_logs/2021-06-22T15_04_53_760Z-debug.log
```

Comprobando en macOS, devuelve como resultado esto.

Comment: Racias Me salio

Comment: Fantástico, no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta si te ha servido!